# OutputCache - specify what to cache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

Im using OutputCache attribute [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]  to cache a controller that returns a view. But the view contains a Helper Method that shows certain information depending on a Web.config property. Problem is that this information is also cached. Is there som way to not cache the helper method information.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately ASP.NET MVC 2 and later do not support [donut caching](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx):

> Due to differences in the way that ASP.NET MVC 2 processes request,
>   data within the substitution block can be cached when it shouldn’t be.
>   Substitution caching for ASP.NET MVC is not supported and has been
>   removed from our ASP.NET MVC Futures project

And here's a [`great article`](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) explaining how you could achieve this in ASP.NET MVC 3 and later. It is based on the [`ASP.NET MVC Extensible Donut Caching`](http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/) package available on Codeplex.